# MySQL Select Datetime Overlapping Entries

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointment` (
  `appId` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `startDateTime` datetime,
  `duration` time DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Sample Data:

```
appId   startDateTime         duration
1       2015-05-04 16:15:00   00:14:00
2       2015-05-12 08:15:00   05:54:00
3       2015-05-12 08:35:00   02:14:00
4       2016-05-04 08:11:00   04:11:00
5       2015-05-13 19:30:00   02:50:00
```

Expected Output:

```
appId   startDateTime         duration
2       2015-05-12 08:15:00   05:54:00
3       2015-05-12 08:35:00   02:14:00
```

I need a query that is able to check every entry in the table and return and entries that collide. In the sample data above, 2 and 3 will overlap. I can convert both of the fields to unix time and calculate the end time however I am not sure how to compare each entry

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any sample data? and also tell us your expected output.

Comment: Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A ends after Event B begins, and begins before Event B ends.

Comment: @Faisal Done, thanks

Comment: @Strawberry I've no idea how to implement that in code

Comment: Go on. You've heard of both JOINs and comparison operators, so you're half way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Faisal's fiddle...

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for appointment
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `appointment`;
CREATE TABLE `appointment` (
  `appId` tinyint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `startDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of appointment
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `appointment` VALUES 
('1', '2015-05-04 16:15:00', '00:14:00'),
('2', '2015-05-12 08:15:00', '05:54:00'),
('3', '2015-05-12 08:35:00', '02:14:00'),
('4', '2016-05-04 08:11:00', '04:11:00'),
('5', '2015-05-13 19:30:00', '02:50:00');

SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM appointment x
           JOIN appointment y
             ON y.startdatetime < x.startdatetime + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(x.duration) SECOND
            AND y.startdatetime + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(y.duration) SECOND > x.startdatetime
            AND y.appid <> x.appid;


    appId startDateTime       duration
        3 12.05.2015 08:35:00 02:14:00
        2 12.05.2015 08:15:00 05:54:00
```

http://rextester.com/YJA59081

Comment: What is "y.appid <> x.appid;" doing?

Comment: It's ignoring events which overlap themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below query. Hope it should be solve your problem.

```
SELECT
    tbl1.*
FROM
    appointment tbl1,
    appointment tbl2
WHERE
    tbl2.appId <> tbl1.appId
AND tbl2.startDateTime < tbl1.startDateTime + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(tbl1.duration) SECOND
AND tbl2.startDateTime + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(tbl2.duration) SECOND > tbl1.startDateTime;
```

By clicking on the below link you can see your expected result in live which you want.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/OCD82633)

Comment: I doubt it somehow

Comment: @strawberry why you doubt? can you explain it?

Comment: Just because two events occur on the psame day, it doesn't mean they overlap

Comment: please see the sql fiddle demo. it will gives me the right result what he wants.

Comment: Yes. But only coincidentally.